# What settings need to do in following senario to validate Sharepoint Site url in VS 2012?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012, domain

Question may be basic, but scenario is not understood. 
scenario is I am having the SharePoint 2010 installed on Windows Server 8 under Domain1. My Developer machine also under Domain 1. But while creating the web part it is asking to validate the site url. I am providing `http://myserverIPAddress:Port/sites/xyzsitename`
On developer machine I am logged in with server domain user. But it is not resolving site url.

It is showing me error like :

[image]

Also one more thing need to be added, when I selects the Visual Webpart template in VS 2012 it ask me to open VS in different permissions elevated permission I guess. But the domain user with I am logged in is not administrator for developer machine. don't understand what is going on.

Comment: give access to current user in content database

Comment: Means in sql content db => security=>login do I need to add domain user on server ?

Comment: yes, add server roles dbcreator,public,securityadmin,sysadmin

Comment: server role in sql server  in mai security node or to sharepoint db only?

Comment: Go to SQL Server --> Security --> login --> Your user --> Properties -->Select server roles and give access

Comment: No, didn't worked. Do I need to restart something?

Comment: added permission on content  database? db_owner?

Comment: Yes. SharePoint_AdminContent_(guid) => Security=>Users=>Properties=>General=> Set DBOwner. But didn't worked. I restarted VS again and trid but no luck Same permissions given to SharePoint_Config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37805/discussion-between-rajesh-joshi-and-red-swan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with server , you can't use another machine to deploy solution. You must need to login to server and develop solution there only.